# How to check that a matrix contains a zero column?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a large matrix, I'd like to check that it has a column of all zeros somewhere in it. How to do that in numpy?

Comment: If there is a column of zeros, do you need the column index, or do you just need "yes or no"?

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser yes or no

Comment: A bad way ::  Try to invert it :-P (if it has a column of all zeros, it's singular)

Comment: @mgilson: Inverting the matrix is not a good test of "has a 0 column": [[1, 1], [1, 1]] cannot be inverted, for example.

Comment: @EOL -- I did preface my comment by "A bad way" ... I also didn't post it as an answer as It certainly wasn't worth an answer.  I suppose that I just wanted to inject a small bit of linear algebra into our mundane programming lives ... :-).  But, FWIW, I'm glad you're keeping me honest.

Comment: @mgilson: I thought that "a bad way" meant that it was not efficient, not that it did not work. :)

Answer (score 18):

Here's one way:

```
In [19]: a
Out[19]: 
array([[9, 4, 0, 0, 7, 2, 0, 4, 0, 1, 2],
       [0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 7, 6, 0, 6, 2, 0],
       [6, 8, 0, 4, 0, 6, 2, 0, 8, 0, 3],
       [5, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 8]])

In [20]: (~a.any(axis=0)).any()
Out[20]: True
```

If you later decide that you need the column index:

```
In [26]: numpy.where(~a.any(axis=0))[0]
Out[26]: array([2])
```

Comment: what's `where`? ok, it's referring to numpy.where

Answer (score 4):

Create an `equals 0` mask (`mat == 0`), and run `all` on it along an axis.

```
(mat == 0).all(axis=0).any()
```

Comment: Warren Weckesser's solution is likely to be faster, because `any()` probably stops checking non-zero lines very early, whereas `mat == 0` performs the comparison on every single element of the array, which is slower.

Comment: @EOL yes i agree. also `mat == 0` creates a temporary bool array with the same shape as `mat`, whereas Warren's `mat.any(axis=0)` only creates a temporary 1d array of size `mat.shape[1]`, which is another reason for my solution to be slower (but perhaps a bit more readable for some).

Comment: This approach has the advantage that it's more easily generalizable to more complex conditions.