# Finding which rows have all elements as zeros in a matrix with numpy

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I have a large `numpy` matrix `M`. Some of the rows of the matrix have all of their elements as zero and I need to get the indices of those rows. The naive approach I'm considering is to loop through each row in the matrix and then check each elements.

What would be a better and a faster approach to accomplish this using `numpy`?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Here's one way.  I assume numpy has been imported using `import numpy as np`.

```
In [20]: a
Out[20]: 
array([[0, 1, 0],
       [1, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 0]])

In [21]: np.where(~a.any(axis=1))[0]
Out[21]: array([2, 4])
```

It's a slight variation of this answer: [How to check that a matrix contains a zero column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16092557/how-to-check-that-a-matrix-contains-a-zero-column/16092714#16092714)

Here's what's going on:

The `any` method returns True if any value in the array is "truthy".  Nonzero numbers are considered True, and 0 is considered False.  By using the argument `axis=1`, the method is applied to each row.  For the example `a`, we have:

```
In [32]: a.any(axis=1)
Out[32]: array([ True,  True, False,  True, False], dtype=bool)
```

So each value indicates whether the corresponding row contains a nonzero value.  The `~` operator is the binary "not" or complement:

```
In [33]: ~a.any(axis=1)
Out[33]: array([False, False,  True, False,  True], dtype=bool)
```

(An alternative expression that gives the same result is `(a == 0).all(axis=1)`.)

To get the row indices, we use the `where` function.  It returns the indices where its argument is True:

```
In [34]: np.where(~a.any(axis=1))
Out[34]: (array([2, 4]),)
```

Note that `where` returned a tuple containing a single array.  `where` works for n-dimensional arrays, so it always returns a tuple.  We want the single array in that tuple.

```
In [35]: np.where(~a.any(axis=1))[0]
Out[35]: array([2, 4])
```

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer works if the elements are `int(0)`. If you want to find rows where all the values are 0.0 (floats), you have to use `np.isclose()`:

```
print(x)
# output
tensor([[0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
         0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
         0., 1., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
         1., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
         0., 0., 0.],
])
np.where(np.all(np.isclose(labels, 0), axis=1))
(array([ 0, 3]),)
```

Note: this also works with PyTorch Tensors, which is nice for when you want to find zeroed multihot encoding vectors.

Answer (score 1):

Solution using `np.sum`,
useful if you want to use a threshold

```
a = np.array([[1.0, 1.0, 2.99],
          [0.0000054, 0.00000078, 0.00000232],
          [0, 0, 0],
          [1, 1, 0.0],
          [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]])
print(np.where(np.sum(np.abs(a), axis=1)==0)[0])
>>[2 4]
print(np.where(np.sum(np.abs(a), axis=1)<0.0001)[0])
>>[1 2 4]
```

Use `np.prod` to check if row contains atleast one zero element

```
print(np.where(np.prod(a, axis=1)==0)[0])
>>[2 3 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a =  numpy.array([[10,0],[0,0],[0,10]])
isZero = numpy.all(a == 0, axis=1)
deleteFullZero = a[~numpy.all(a== 0, axis=1)] 
#isZero >> [False True False]
#deleteFullZero >> [[10 0][0,10]]
```