# Check if every section of matrix is all 0 using numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I want to check if all entries of a matrix A within 10 indices of a given entry (x,y) are zero. I think something like this should do it

```
(numpy.take(A,[x-10:x+10,y-10:y+10]) == 0).all()
```

but I'm getting a invalid syntax error. Think I'm not constructing the index ranges right, any suggestions?

Comment: This seems similar. Might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23726026/finding-which-rows-have-all-elements-as-zeros-in-a-matrix-with-numpy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't worry about using `take`, just index your array like this:

```
(A[x-10:x+10,y-10:y+10] == 0).all()
```

Answer (score 2):

A simple boolean check against the entries of the submatrix will do

```
np.all(A[x-10:x+11,y-10:y+11]==0)
```

(note the upper index is not included, so I changed to `i-10:i+11`)

Comment: Thanks! Gave maxymoo the check because his answer was first, I think

Comment: maybe maxymoo as first but @mecalinum got it right (i.e. `i+11` not `i+10`).  That should count for something. +1

Answer (score 1):

Suppose `A` is an array of shape (19,19):

```
import numpy as np
H = W = 19
x, y = 1, 1
N = 10
A = np.random.randint(10, size=(H,W))
```

Then

```
In [433]: A[x-N:x+N,y-N:y+N]
Out[433]: array([[4]])
```

Since `x-N` is `1-10 = -9`, `A[x-N:x+N,y-N:y+N]` is equivalent to `A[-9:11,-9:11]`, 
which is equivalent to `A[19-9:11,19-9:11]` which is the same as `A[10:11,10:11]`.
So only one value is selected.

That's not giving you "all entries of a matrix A within 10 indices of a given
entry (x,y)".

Instead, you could generate the desired subregion using a boolean mask:

```
X, Y = np.ogrid[0:H,0:W]
mask = (np.abs(X - x) < N) & (np.abs(Y - y) < N)
```

Once you have the mask, you can select the subregion where the mask is True using `A[mask]`, and test if every value is zero with

```
(A[mask] == 0).all()
```

---

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(2015)
H = W = 19
x, y = 1, 1
N = 10
A = np.random.randint(10, size=(H,W))
print(A[x-N:x+N,y-N:y+N])
# [[4]]

X, Y = np.ogrid[0:H,0:W]
mask = (np.abs(X - x) < N) & (np.abs(Y - y) < N)
print(mask.astype(int))
# [[1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
#  [1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
#  [1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
#  [1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
#  [1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
#  [1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
#  [1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
#  [1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
#  [1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
#  [1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
#  [1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
#  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
#  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
#  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
#  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
#  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
#  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
#  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
#  [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]]

print(A[mask] == 0).all() 
# False
```